# How do I separate the json objects in a get http request in a $scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

```
    [{
  "entityList": [
    {
      "scenarioNo": "SC1",
      "accountingMonExtracted": null,
      "acronym": null,
      "address1": "542 W 27th Street 4th Floor",
      "address2": null,
      "addressType": "MAILING",
      "alternateEmailId": null,
      "alternateFaxNo": null,
     "alternatePhoneNo": null,
      "city": "Bethlehem",
      "country": "US",
      "county": null,
      "firstName": "Thomas",
      "fullName": "Peter Jen",
      "lastName": "Routher",
      "middleName": null,
      "namePrefix": null,
      "nameSuffix": null,
      "primaryAddressYN": "Y",
      "primaryEmailId": "johnmann@yahoo.com",
      "primaryFaxNo": "(406)485-2983",
      "primaryPhoneNo": "(405)452-3645",
      "state": "AB",
      "zipCode": "40007.0",
      "agentType": null,
      "autoCommClosingDays": null,
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,
      "creditTermMonths": null,
      "customerNo": null,
      "doingBusinessAsName": null,
      "eftDraftOption": null,
      "entityType": "INSURED",
      "frequencyDayMonth": null,
      "frequencyDayOfWeek": null,
      "frequencyType": null,
      "invoiceCurrency": "USD",
      "ncanGraceDays": null,
      "outputDeliveryMethod": "M",
      "parentEntityCode": null,
      "paymentMethod": "EFT",
      "process1099Indicator": "N",
      "recurringEFTTokend": null,
      "requestedDueDay": null,
      "sourceSystem": "DPAS",
      "sourceSystemEntityCode": "INS000020",
      "statementFormat": null,
      "statementIndicatorYN": "N",
      "statementMailingDay": null,
      "userRemarks": null,
      "vendorCode": null,
      "ssn": null,
      "taxid": null
    },
    {
      "scenarioNo": "SC2",
      "accountingMonExtracted": null,
      "acronym": null,
      "address1": "542 W 27th Street 4th Floor",
      "address2": null,
      "addressType": "MAILING",
      "alternateEmailId": null,
      "alternateFaxNo": null,
      "alternatePhoneNo": null,
      "city": "Bethlehem",
      "country": "US",
      "county": null,
      "firstName": "Thomas",
      "fullName": "Peter Jen",
      "lastName": "Routher",
      "middleName": null,
      "namePrefix": null,
      "nameSuffix": null,
      "primaryAddressYN": "Y",
      "primaryEmailId": "johnmann@yahoo.com",
      "primaryFaxNo": "(406)485-2983",
      "primaryPhoneNo": "(405)452-3645",
      "state": "AB",
      "zipCode": "40007.0",
      "agentType": null,
      "autoCommClosingDays": null,
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,
      "creditTermMonths": null,
      "customerNo": null,
      "doingBusinessAsName": null,
      "eftDraftOption": null,
      "entityType": "INSURED",
      "frequencyDayMonth": null,
      "frequencyDayOfWeek": null,
      "frequencyType": null,
      "invoiceCurrency": "USD",
      "ncanGraceDays": null,
      "outputDeliveryMethod": "M",
      "parentEntityCode": null,
      "paymentMethod": "EFT",
      "process1099Indicator": "N",
      "recurringEFTTokend": null,
      "requestedDueDay": null,
      "sourceSystem": "DPAS",
      "sourceSystemEntityCode": "INS000040",
      "statementFormat": null,
      "statementIndicatorYN": "N",
      "statementMailingDay": null,
      "userRemarks": null,
      "vendorCode": null,
      "ssn": null,
      "taxid": null
    },
    {
      "scenarioNo": "SC3",
      "accountingMonExtracted": null,
      "acronym": null,
      "address1": "542 W 27th Street 4th Floor",
      "address2": null,
      "addressType": "MAILING",
      "alternateEmailId": null,
      "alternateFaxNo": null,
      "alternatePhoneNo": null,
      "city": "Bethlehem",
      "country": "US",
      "county": null,
      "firstName": "Thomas",
      "fullName": "Peter Jen",
      "lastName": "Routher",
      "middleName": null,
      "namePrefix": null,
      "nameSuffix": null,
      "primaryAddressYN": "Y",
      "primaryEmailId": "johnmann@yahoo.com",
      "primaryFaxNo": "(406)485-2983",
      "primaryPhoneNo": "(405)452-3645",
      "state": "AB",
      "zipCode": "40007.0",
      "agentType": null,
      "autoCommClosingDays": null,
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,
      "creditTermMonths": null,
      "customerNo": null,
      "doingBusinessAsName": null,
      "eftDraftOption": null,
      "entityType": "INSURED",
      "frequencyDayMonth": null,
      "frequencyDayOfWeek": null,
      "frequencyType": null,
      "invoiceCurrency": "USD",
      "ncanGraceDays": null,
     "outputDeliveryMethod": "M",
      "parentEntityCode": null,
      "paymentMethod": "EFT",
      "process1099Indicator": "N",
      "recurringEFTTokend": null,
      "requestedDueDay": null,
      "sourceSystem": "DPAS",
      "sourceSystemEntityCode": "INS000060",
      "statementFormat": null,
      "statementIndicatorYN": "N",
      "statementMailingDay": null,
      "userRemarks": null,
      "vendorCode": null,
      "ssn": null,
      "taxid": null
    },
    {
      "scenarioNo": "SC4",
      "accountingMonExtracted": null,
      "acronym": null,
      "address1": "542 W 27th Street 4th Floor",
      "address2": null,
      "addressType": "MAILING",
      "alternateEmailId": null,
      "alternateFaxNo": null,
      "alternatePhoneNo": null,
      "city": "Bethlehem",
      "country": "US",
      "county": null,
      "firstName": "Thomas",
      "fullName": "Peter Jen",
      "lastName": "Routher",
      "middleName": null,
      "namePrefix": null,
      "nameSuffix": null,
      "primaryAddressYN": "Y",
      "primaryEmailId": "johnmann@yahoo.com",
      "primaryFaxNo": "(406)485-2983",
      "primaryPhoneNo": "(405)452-3645",
      "state": "AB",
      "zipCode": "40007.0",
      "agentType": null,
      "autoCommClosingDays": null,
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,
      "creditTermMonths": null,
      "customerNo": null,
      "doingBusinessAsName": null,
      "eftDraftOption": null,
      "entityType": "INSURED",
      "frequencyDayMonth": null,
      "frequencyDayOfWeek": null,
      "frequencyType": null,
      "invoiceCurrency": "USD",
      "ncanGraceDays": null,
      "outputDeliveryMethod": "M",
      "parentEntityCode": null,
      "paymentMethod": "EFT",
      "process1099Indicator": "N",
      "recurringEFTTokend": null,
      "requestedDueDay": null,
      "sourceSystem": "DPAS",
      "sourceSystemEntityCode": "INS000080",
      "statementFormat": null,
      "statementIndicatorYN": "N",
      "statementMailingDay": null,
      "userRemarks": null,
      "vendorCode": null,
      "ssn": null,
      "taxid": null
    }
  ],
  "paymentList": [{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "3",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "2",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "1",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    }],
    "returnpaymentList": [{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "3",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "2",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "1",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    }],
    "whatifList": [{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "3",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "2",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "1",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    }],
  "userAuthenticationList": {
   "userName": "ABC",
    "password": "ABC",
    "ssoUserName": null,
    "ssoToken": null,
    "token": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "iwaadomain": null,
    "iwaauser": null,
    "iwaasecretKey": null
  },
  "requestHeaderList": {
    "scenarioID": "SA",
    "countOfRecords": "1212",
    "countOfDeposits": null,
    "countOfTransactions": null,
    "requestDate": null,
    "sourceSystemRequestNo": null,
    "totalPaymentAmount": null
  }
}]
```

How do I access the individual objects such as entity request headers payment return payment etc ?
I have to separate the objects in respectively variable which are then used to populate on screen using ng-model and repeat.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong format I posted the question from my phone....I have written a http get request to obtain this above json data then I store it in a $scope.multibleobjects =response.data

Comment: I want to store the resptive objects in similar $scope.entity $payment etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can access to the data like this :

```
alert($scope.data[0].requestHeaderList.scenarioID);  // one element
$scope.reqheaderData = $scope.data[0].requestHeaderList; // Whole request part
$scope.entity = $scope.data[0].entityList; // the list of entities
// same for other parts
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.data =  [{
  "entityList": [
    {
      "scenarioNo": "SC1",
      "accountingMonExtracted": null,
      "acronym": null,
      "address1": "542 W 27th Street 4th Floor",
      "address2": null,
      "addressType": "MAILING",
      "alternateEmailId": null,
      "alternateFaxNo": null,
     "alternatePhoneNo": null,
      "city": "Bethlehem",
      "country": "US",
      "county": null,
      "firstName": "Thomas",
      "fullName": "Peter Jen",
      "lastName": "Routher",
      "middleName": null,
      "namePrefix": null,
      "nameSuffix": null,
      "primaryAddressYN": "Y",
      "primaryEmailId": "johnmann@yahoo.com",
      "primaryFaxNo": "(406)485-2983",
      "primaryPhoneNo": "(405)452-3645",
      "state": "AB",
      "zipCode": "40007.0",
      "agentType": null,
      "autoCommClosingDays": null,
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,
      "creditTermMonths": null,
      "customerNo": null,
      "doingBusinessAsName": null,
      "eftDraftOption": null,
      "entityType": "INSURED",
      "frequencyDayMonth": null,
      "frequencyDayOfWeek": null,
      "frequencyType": null,
      "invoiceCurrency": "USD",
      "ncanGraceDays": null,
      "outputDeliveryMethod": "M",
      "parentEntityCode": null,
      "paymentMethod": "EFT",
      "process1099Indicator": "N",
      "recurringEFTTokend": null,
      "requestedDueDay": null,
      "sourceSystem": "DPAS",
      "sourceSystemEntityCode": "INS000020",
      "statementFormat": null,
      "statementIndicatorYN": "N",
      "statementMailingDay": null,
      "userRemarks": null,
      "vendorCode": null,
      "ssn": null,
      "taxid": null
    },
    {
      "scenarioNo": "SC2",
      "accountingMonExtracted": null,
      "acronym": null,
      "address1": "542 W 27th Street 4th Floor",
      "address2": null,
      "addressType": "MAILING",
      "alternateEmailId": null,
      "alternateFaxNo": null,
      "alternatePhoneNo": null,
      "city": "Bethlehem",
      "country": "US",
      "county": null,
      "firstName": "Thomas",
      "fullName": "Peter Jen",
      "lastName": "Routher",
      "middleName": null,
      "namePrefix": null,
      "nameSuffix": null,
      "primaryAddressYN": "Y",
      "primaryEmailId": "johnmann@yahoo.com",
      "primaryFaxNo": "(406)485-2983",
      "primaryPhoneNo": "(405)452-3645",
      "state": "AB",
      "zipCode": "40007.0",
      "agentType": null,
      "autoCommClosingDays": null,
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,
      "creditTermMonths": null,
      "customerNo": null,
      "doingBusinessAsName": null,
      "eftDraftOption": null,
      "entityType": "INSURED",
      "frequencyDayMonth": null,
      "frequencyDayOfWeek": null,
      "frequencyType": null,
      "invoiceCurrency": "USD",
      "ncanGraceDays": null,
      "outputDeliveryMethod": "M",
      "parentEntityCode": null,
      "paymentMethod": "EFT",
      "process1099Indicator": "N",
      "recurringEFTTokend": null,
      "requestedDueDay": null,
      "sourceSystem": "DPAS",
      "sourceSystemEntityCode": "INS000040",
      "statementFormat": null,
      "statementIndicatorYN": "N",
      "statementMailingDay": null,
      "userRemarks": null,
      "vendorCode": null,
      "ssn": null,
      "taxid": null
    },
    {
      "scenarioNo": "SC3",
      "accountingMonExtracted": null,
      "acronym": null,
      "address1": "542 W 27th Street 4th Floor",
      "address2": null,
      "addressType": "MAILING",
      "alternateEmailId": null,
      "alternateFaxNo": null,
      "alternatePhoneNo": null,
      "city": "Bethlehem",
      "country": "US",
      "county": null,
      "firstName": "Thomas",
      "fullName": "Peter Jen",
      "lastName": "Routher",
      "middleName": null,
      "namePrefix": null,
      "nameSuffix": null,
      "primaryAddressYN": "Y",
      "primaryEmailId": "johnmann@yahoo.com",
      "primaryFaxNo": "(406)485-2983",
      "primaryPhoneNo": "(405)452-3645",
      "state": "AB",
      "zipCode": "40007.0",
      "agentType": null,
      "autoCommClosingDays": null,
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,
      "creditTermMonths": null,
      "customerNo": null,
      "doingBusinessAsName": null,
      "eftDraftOption": null,
      "entityType": "INSURED",
      "frequencyDayMonth": null,
      "frequencyDayOfWeek": null,
      "frequencyType": null,
      "invoiceCurrency": "USD",
      "ncanGraceDays": null,
     "outputDeliveryMethod": "M",
      "parentEntityCode": null,
      "paymentMethod": "EFT",
      "process1099Indicator": "N",
      "recurringEFTTokend": null,
      "requestedDueDay": null,
      "sourceSystem": "DPAS",
      "sourceSystemEntityCode": "INS000060",
      "statementFormat": null,
      "statementIndicatorYN": "N",
      "statementMailingDay": null,
      "userRemarks": null,
      "vendorCode": null,
      "ssn": null,
      "taxid": null
    },
    {
      "scenarioNo": "SC4",
      "accountingMonExtracted": null,
      "acronym": null,
      "address1": "542 W 27th Street 4th Floor",
      "address2": null,
      "addressType": "MAILING",
      "alternateEmailId": null,
      "alternateFaxNo": null,
      "alternatePhoneNo": null,
      "city": "Bethlehem",
      "country": "US",
      "county": null,
      "firstName": "Thomas",
      "fullName": "Peter Jen",
      "lastName": "Routher",
      "middleName": null,
      "namePrefix": null,
      "nameSuffix": null,
      "primaryAddressYN": "Y",
      "primaryEmailId": "johnmann@yahoo.com",
      "primaryFaxNo": "(406)485-2983",
      "primaryPhoneNo": "(405)452-3645",
      "state": "AB",
      "zipCode": "40007.0",
      "agentType": null,
      "autoCommClosingDays": null,
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,
      "creditTermMonths": null,
      "customerNo": null,
      "doingBusinessAsName": null,
      "eftDraftOption": null,
      "entityType": "INSURED",
      "frequencyDayMonth": null,
      "frequencyDayOfWeek": null,
      "frequencyType": null,
      "invoiceCurrency": "USD",
      "ncanGraceDays": null,
      "outputDeliveryMethod": "M",
      "parentEntityCode": null,
      "paymentMethod": "EFT",
      "process1099Indicator": "N",
      "recurringEFTTokend": null,
      "requestedDueDay": null,
      "sourceSystem": "DPAS",
      "sourceSystemEntityCode": "INS000080",
      "statementFormat": null,
      "statementIndicatorYN": "N",
      "statementMailingDay": null,
      "userRemarks": null,
      "vendorCode": null,
      "ssn": null,
      "taxid": null
    }
  ],
  "paymentList": [{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "3",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "2",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "1",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    }],
    "returnpaymentList": [{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "3",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "2",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "1",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    }],
    "whatifList": [{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "3",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "2",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    },{

      "autoCommClosingDays": "1",
      "autoCommExtractionYN": null,
      "billingContactName": "Peter Jen",
      "commissionCurrency": null,
      "commissionEFTTokenId": null,
      "commissionEntityYN": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityCode": null,
      "commissionPayeeEntityType": null,
      "commissionPaymentMethod": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityCode": null,
      "commissionStatementEntityType": null,
      "creditTermDays": null,

    }],
  "userAuthenticationList": {
   "userName": "ABC",
    "password": "ABC",
    "ssoUserName": null,
    "ssoToken": null,
    "token": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "iwaadomain": null,
    "iwaauser": null,
    "iwaasecretKey": null
  },
  "requestHeaderList": {
    "scenarioID": "SA",
    "countOfRecords": "1212",
    "countOfDeposits": null,
    "countOfTransactions": null,
    "requestDate": null,
    "sourceSystemRequestNo": null,
    "totalPaymentAmount": null
  }
}];
alert($scope.data[0].requestHeaderList.scenarioID);

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I try to print data[0] I get a error in console if I try to access data[0] saying 0 is not defined

Comment: It work on my laptop! do you use list or set make sure the $scope.data is a list mot set !

Comment: $scope.data is going to be a object

Comment: check my snippet!

Comment: The Json you have posted is a List not an Object!